# Convert Custom Time Format to a Separate Format

Tags: php, date, date-format, strtotime

I have a custom date format the `strtotime()` doesn't recognize, and since I'm working with jquery / the user - I want the user to see a specific formatted date so no compromise. Is there a separate method to convert date formats? Currently my format looks like this: `D - M d, Y` and I want to convert it over to something like this: `Ymd` - is there a different function than `strtotime()`?

If it matters I am using WordPress but it didn't seem to have any helpful date formatting functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try the `DateTime` object function [createFromFormat](http://us.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php)

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('D - M d, Y', 'your date here');
echo $date->format('Ymd');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`DateTime::createFromFormat()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) to parse the input into a `DateTime` object. Then use [`DateTime::format()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php) to convert to the desired output format:

```
// parse input to a DateTime object
$dateTime = DateTime::createFromFormat('D - M d, Y');

// format to desired output format
echo $dateTime->format('Ymd');
```